# Could not install sudo apt-get install libshogun17

Tags: shogun

When trying to install shogun im getting this error. Can some one suggest a solution?
N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucf-dist' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Unable to locate package libshogun17

Im using ubuntu operating system.

Answer (score 0):

See this [explanation of the origin and purpose of .ucf-dist files.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/572976/what-to-do-now-update-just-after-install/573091#573091) This means you can either ignore the notice (that's what the N: prefix stands for) or remove said file.

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades.ucf-dist
```

Comment: I did this way, but still I got E: Unable to locate package libshogun17,

Answer (score 0):

libshogun17 is not part of ubuntu by default. Currently we supply two different ppa's for xenial and trusty:

- for nightly builds: https://launchpad.net/~shogun-toolbox/+archive/ubuntu/nightly
- for stable releases: https://launchpad.net/~shogun-toolbox/+archive/ubuntu/stable

please follow the instruction either the given page or http://shogun.ml/install#ubuntu how to add the ppa to your system.

Note, as mentioned above those PPAs only supply packages for ubuntu **trusty** or **xenial**.

Comment: just an update: there's a xenial package in stable ppa